# logback equivalent of log4j RewriteAppender

Tags: logging, log4j, logback

I'm attempting to replicate some functionality that a co-worker implemented under log4j for logback.

Essentially the functionality utilizes the RewriteAppender from log4j to hide sensitive information (defined by a regex pattern) in the logs by filtering them out.

Is there a mechanism similar to this under logback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various filtering options available in logback: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html
Those also include the ability to write your own filters, where you could then implement the Regex-filtering - if you only want to either accept or deny the logging event.

If you intend to change the message depending on a pattern, you'll probably have no other choice than to implement your own Appender class.

Though I would suggest not even handing sensitive information to the logging framework. Those shouldn't even leave the application at all (which, of course, is only possible if you have access to the code).

Edit: After checking again (there was some nagging doubt in the back of my mind), you could also use %replace in your layout-pattern. Have a look at it's description here: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#replace. It's replacement of parts of the log-message based on a regex, so might be just the thing you are looking for.